# OpenXML returning NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I am trying to import xml into my database with the following query using OpenXML in Microsoft SQL Server:

```
DECLARE @xml XML;
DECLARE @y INT;

SET @xml
    = '<ArrayOfArticle xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Article>
    <ScriptId xmlns="https://test.com/">5135399</ScriptId>
    <Title xmlns="https://test.com/">Stocks divided into two corners</Title>
    <Mediatype xmlns="https://test.com/">News papeer</Mediatype>
    <Abstract xmlns="https://test.com/">Foreign capital doubled this year.</Abstract>
    <ScriptDate xmlns="https://test.com/">2017-12-30T00:00:00</ScriptDate>
    <ScriptTypeId xmlns="https://test.com/">1</ScriptTypeId>
    <ScriptType xmlns="https://test.com/">News general</ScriptType>
    <Media xmlns="https://test.com/">Times</Media>
    <ArticleUrl xmlns="https://test.com/">http://test.com</ArticleUrl>
    <AnalysisResult xmlns="https://test.com/">
      <Analysis>
        <Regno>111</Regno>
        <Name>New York Times</Name>
        <Result>1</Result>
        <ResultName>Positive</ResultName>
      </Analysis>
      <Analysis>
        <Regno>222</Regno>
        <Name>Washington Post</Name>
        <Result>1</Result>
        <ResultName>Negative</ResultName>
      </Analysis>
    </AnalysisResult>
    <FacebookStats xmlns="https://test.com/">
      <ShareCount xsi:nil="true" />
      <LikeCount xsi:nil="true" />
      <CommentCount xsi:nil="true" />
      <TotalCount xsi:nil="true" />
    </FacebookStats>
    <MediaScore xmlns="https://test.com/">
      <MediaScore>
        <Regno>111</Regno>
        <CompanyName>New York Times</CompanyName>
        <MediaScoreID>2</MediaScoreID>
        <Name>Neither</Name>
      </MediaScore>
      <MediaScore>
        <Regno>222</Regno>
        <CompanyName>Washington Post</CompanyName>
        <MediaScoreID>2</MediaScoreID>
        <Name>Neither</Name>
      </MediaScore>
    </MediaScore>
    <Page xmlns="https://test.com/">26</Page>
    <ProgramId xmlns="https://test.com/">0</ProgramId>
    <ProgramTime xmlns="https://test.com/" xsi:nil="true" />
    <ProgramLength xmlns="https://test.com/">0</ProgramLength>
    <ProgramOrder xmlns="https://test.com/">0</ProgramOrder>
  </Article>
 </ArrayOfArticle>';

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @y OUTPUT, @xml;
SELECT *
FROM
    OPENXML(@y, '/ArrayOfArticle/Article', 1)
    WITH
    (
        ScriptId VARCHAR(20),
        Title VARCHAR(30),
        Mediatype VARCHAR(30)
    );
```

The query however only returns NULL values. What am I missing here? Would it be optimal to import the XML using SSIS instead. Not sure how much more details I can give at the given hour.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not use `FROM OPENXML`. This approach (together with the corresponding SPs to prepare and to remove a document) is outdated and should not be used any more.

Try the XML type's native methods, in this case `.value()`:

Your XML is rather weird - concerning namespaces. If its creation is under your control you should try to clean this namespace mess. The unusual thing is, that your XML declares **default** namespaces over and over.

You can use the *deep search with `//`* together with a namespace wildcard `*:`

```
--GetItEasyCheesy (not recommended)
SELECT @xml.value(N'(//*:ScriptId)[1]',N'int') AS ScriptId
      ,@xml.value(N'(//*:Title)[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Title
      ,@xml.value(N'(//*:Mediatype )[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Mediatype ;
```

You can declare the namespace as default, but in this case you must wildcard the outer elements, as they are not part of this namespace:

```
--Use a default namespace
WITH XMLNAMESPACES(DEFAULT 'https://test.com/') 
SELECT @xml.value(N'(/*:ArrayOfArticle/*:Article/ScriptId/text())[1]',N'int') AS ScriptId
      ,@xml.value(N'(/*:ArrayOfArticle/*:Article/Title/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Title
      ,@xml.value(N'(/*:ArrayOfArticle/*:Article/Mediatype/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Mediatype;
```

The recommended approach is to bind the inner namespace to a prefix and use this

```
--Recommended
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('https://test.com/' AS ns) 
SELECT @xml.value(N'(/ArrayOfArticle/Article/ns:ScriptId/text())[1]',N'int') AS ScriptId
      ,@xml.value(N'(/ArrayOfArticle/Article/ns:Title/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Title
      ,@xml.value(N'(/ArrayOfArticle/Article/ns:Mediatype/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Mediatype;
```

If your `<ArrayOfArticles>` contains more than one `<Article>` you can use `.nodes()` to get alle of them as derived table. In this case the query is

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES('https://test.com/' AS ns) 
SELECT art.value(N'(ns:ScriptId/text())[1]',N'int') AS Recommended
      ,art.value(N'(ns:Title/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Title
      ,art.value(N'(ns:Mediatype/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS Mediatype
FROM @xml.nodes(N'/ArrayOfArticle/Article') AS A(art);
```

Comment: Works like a charm. How would I be able to get the nested values? For example CompanyName inside MediaScore?

Comment: @theOGloc: Please ask a new question.  This answer fully addresses your original question.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

your XML contains namespaces, I'd use xquery in order to extract the data from your XML

**UPDATE** with additional elements extract

```
    DECLARE @xml XML;
    SET @xml
        = '<ArrayOfArticle xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
      <Article>
        <ScriptId xmlns="https://test.com/">5135399</ScriptId>
        <Title xmlns="https://test.com/">Stocks divided into two corners</Title>
        <Mediatype xmlns="https://test.com/">News papeer</Mediatype>
        <Abstract xmlns="https://test.com/">Foreign capital doubled this year.</Abstract>
        <ScriptDate xmlns="https://test.com/">2017-12-30T00:00:00</ScriptDate>
        <ScriptTypeId xmlns="https://test.com/">1</ScriptTypeId>
        <ScriptType xmlns="https://test.com/">News general</ScriptType>
        <Media xmlns="https://test.com/">Times</Media>
        <ArticleUrl xmlns="https://test.com/">http://test.com</ArticleUrl>
        <AnalysisResult xmlns="https://test.com/">
          <Analysis>
            <Regno>111</Regno>
            <Name>New York Times</Name>
            <Result>1</Result>
            <ResultName>Positive</ResultName>
          </Analysis>
          <Analysis>
            <Regno>222</Regno>
            <Name>Washington Post</Name>
            <Result>1</Result>
            <ResultName>Negative</ResultName>
          </Analysis>
        </AnalysisResult>
        <FacebookStats xmlns="https://test.com/">
          <ShareCount xsi:nil="true" />
          <LikeCount xsi:nil="true" />
          <CommentCount xsi:nil="true" />
          <TotalCount xsi:nil="true" />
        </FacebookStats>
        <MediaScore xmlns="https://test.com/">
          <MediaScore>
            <Regno>111</Regno>
            <CompanyName>New York Times</CompanyName>
            <MediaScoreID>2</MediaScoreID>
            <Name>Neither</Name>
          </MediaScore>
          <MediaScore>
            <Regno>222</Regno>
            <CompanyName>Washington Post</CompanyName>
            <MediaScoreID>2</MediaScoreID>
            <Name>Neither</Name>
          </MediaScore>
        </MediaScore>
        <Page xmlns="https://test.com/">26</Page>
        <ProgramId xmlns="https://test.com/">0</ProgramId>
        <ProgramTime xmlns="https://test.com/" xsi:nil="true" />
        <ProgramLength xmlns="https://test.com/">0</ProgramLength>
        <ProgramOrder xmlns="https://test.com/">0</ProgramOrder>
      </Article>
     </ArrayOfArticle>'

    DECLARE @T TABLE (XmlCol XML)
    INSERT INTO @T 
    SELECT @xml


    ;WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('https://test.com/' as p1)
    SELECT z.t.value ('../../p1:ScriptId[1]',' varchar(100)') ScriptId,
           z.t.value ('../../p1:Title[1]',' varchar(100)') Title,
           z.t.value ('../../p1:Mediatype[1]',' varchar(100)') Mediatype,
           z.t.value ('p1:CompanyName[1]', 'varchar(100)') CompanyName
                FROM @T t
        CROSS APPLY XmlCol.nodes ('/ArrayOfArticle/Article/p1:MediaScore/p1:MediaScore') z(t)
```

Comment: Good answer, +1 from my side

Comment: Works like a charm. How would I be able to get the nested values? For example CompanyName inside MediaScore?

Comment: @theOGloc, I've updated the script with the extract of the CompanyName from the nested MediaScore

Answer (score 1):

```
DECLARE @y INT

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @y OUTPUT, @xml,
'<ns xmlns:x="https://test.com/"/>'

SELECT *
FROM
    OPENXML(@y, '/ArrayOfArticle/Article', 2)
    WITH
    (
        [ScriptId] VARCHAR(20) 'x:ScriptId', --<< and so on
        [Title] VARCHAR(30),
        Mediatype VARCHAR(30)
    )

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @y  --<< lost in your code
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand that.